New Trace and Span Generated even after using TraceId and SpanID from Remote Context
I am injecting the spanId and traceId flowing via HTTP header to to build a  remote context and creating new Span, however the new span does not get the parent trace and span but created its own trace id. As a result it does not get attached to the desired parent span.
OpenTelemetry openTelemetry = AutoConfiguredOpenTelemetrySdk.initialize().getOpenTelemetrySdk();

Tracer tracer = openTelemetry.getTracer(INSTRUMENTATION_NAME);

String[] ids = (headers.get("x-cloud-trace-context").split(";"))[0].split("/");

SpanContext remoteContext = SpanContext.createFromRemoteParent(
                    ids[0],
                    ids[1],
                    TraceFlags.getSampled(),
                    TraceState.getDefault());

Span span = tracer
            .spanBuilder("Make Call Out")
            .setParent(Context.current().with(Span.wrap(remoteContext)))
            .startSpan();

Span childSpan = tracer.spanBuilder("HTTP Request")
            .setParent(Context.current().with(span))
            .startSpan();
//Some Work
childSpan.end();
span.end();


When I see trace explorer the default trace (from Cloud Run endpoint invocation ) and custom trace (from Java code) has two different traces. Ideally they should be hooked in same hierarchy in single trace.


Related Example

I realised that the span id that is extracted from the request header was a decimal number however while creating the context it expects in a hexadecimal format.

SPAN_ID is a 64-bit decimal representation of the unsigned span ID.

Reference - https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/trace-context#http-requests
